# what best free thumbnails library for php?

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails

I cant install imagic so I need to use GD..

maybe [phpThumb()](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/)
but latest version released May 28, 2008

Comment: What does your library need to do?

Comment: it should make all kinds of thumbs centered, transparent background, all kinds of watermarks maybe have its own way of handling cashe or folders structure.. I just don't need worry about thumbs if I need they apears if I not so I delete them ant when they are needed they may recreate or somthing. Thats all I need now but in the future who knows.. so just looking for bestest library on the internet :) ofcourse it should be not the slowest one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try PHPThumb http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/

also

WideImage http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/

The above two are part of the top50 PHP classes on Hotscripts. I wouldnt worry about the age of the last update of the script. Just because its no longer updated doesnt mean its no good. It can mean that the code has been written for a job and it achieves it to the best of its ability and there is no need to improve on it

Comment: maybe dosnt mean its no good but also i dont want go with alot of warnings.. maybe most of them is deprecated functions but i dont want that code like that. wideimage is not fot thumbs I think :) and phpthumb maybe but phpThumb() has a lot better cache system so I am back to phpThumb() with some bugs.. unles you know more alternatives.

Comment: Both of the above are still active projects. Plus if they are built for PHP which they are then you are not going to have to worry about depreciated functions unless you plan on moving to PHP 6 soon. And WideImage does do thumbnails. Did you even look at the URL? Even on the home page is example code of making a thumbnail image of a larger one...

Comment: http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/ tested with PHP 5.4.x working perfectly :D

Comment: phpthumb.gxdlabs.com doesn't seems to have issues piling up, WideImage has last changes from 2011.

Answer (score 0):

**CImage** (Works with PHP GD)

Server-side image resizing and cropping on the fly with caching of generated image-files using PHP.
Requires PHP 5.3+ and soon PHP 5.4+

GITHUB
https://github.com/mosbth/cimage

Another alternative would be **SLIR** (Works with PHP GD)

(Smart Lencioni Image Resizer) resizes images, intelligently sharpens, crops based on width:height ratios, color fills transparent GIFs and PNGs, and caches variations for optimal performance. Requires PHP 5.1.2+

Apparently it doesn't support external images. But for local it's fine.

GITHUB
https://github.com/lencioni/SLIR

**Author**: *TimThumb is no longer supported or maintained. You can read the reasons why on my blog: [TimThumb End of Life][1]*

You also have **TimThumb** (works with PHP GD)

It's widely used in the Wordpress world. It can be implemented almost identically to phpThumb but requires PHP 5.2+

GOOGLE CODE
https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

TIMTHUMB PAGE
http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/

Comment: If you consider using TimThumb please first read this article written by the generator of TimTumb. [I No Longer Use TimThumb – Here’s What I do Instead](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2014/09/timthumb-end-life/)

Comment: @effe I have to agree with that. I'm still using phpThumb, still works. Editing post.